# What is 'catcomplete' in jQuery's autocomplete plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The [jQuery UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) autocomplete plugin uses the `catcomplete` function. I'm new to the jQuery syntax. How can I to read it?

```
$("#searchTextBox").catcomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: $("#searchTextBox").data("url"),
    open: function () {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css({
            left: $(".ui-autocomplete").position().left - 50 + "px",
            top: $(".ui-autocomplete").position().top - 12 + "px"
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        /* Code */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> What is catcomplete?

`catcomplete` is a property that appears on jQuery objects. It is not part of core jQuery so there is presumably some other script on the page that is adding it.

> How does jQuery's autocomplete call it?

I can't find `catcomplete` mentioned anywhere in the documentation for autocomplete, so it probably doesn't. It just modifies the CSS of elements in the page with class names that suggest they are normally influenced by autocomplete.

> What are minLength, source, open and select?

Properties of the object that gets passed as an argument to the `catcomplete` complete function. You should read the catcomplete documentation to find out what they mean.

> Who decided their name?

The author(s) of catcomplete

> Which part of the code knows how to use them?

The catcomplete script

> Are they a part of standard jQuery?

No.

> Is catcomplete a function?

Yes, it has `(…)` after it to call it and does not (presumably) throw an exception.

> What is `$("#searchTextBox").Example({})?` doing? Am I defining an array and passing it to a function called Example?

No. You are creating an object. An array would be `[]`.

> Or am I defining a function called Example which initializes an anonymous Array?

No. That would be:

```
function Example() {
    var foo = [];
}
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Comment: last is wrong, it initializes named array. Correct is: `function Example(){[];}` or `function Example{Array();}`

Comment: @vp_arth — There's no such thing as a named array (or an anonymous array for that matter).

Comment: @vp_arth the hell is a "named array"? Both of those you posted are _functions_. Yes, they are named but named _functions_. As opposed to anonymous functions like `function() {}` No, that array they have is completely useless since it's initialised and thrown away.

Comment: It was just a little joke. But anonymous arrays are not useless: `[a, b, c].forEach(...)`. "Anonymous" term itself means there are not any links to it and it will be purged from memory when current call finishes.